# Any ROS tutorial which uses custom made msgs to publish data over topic

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found a lot of tutorials in which messages files which are already provided by ROS are used to publish data over a topic. However I am planning on making my own custom messages to publish over ROS. Is there any tutorials which helps in that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71395/any-ros-tutorial-which-uses-custom-made-msgs-to-publish-data-over-topic/) by [micheal](https://answers.ros.org/users/5403/micheal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2013-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROSNodeTutorialC%2B%2B) is a tutorial available for using ROS in C++ and Python to send custom messages and use dynamic reconfigure.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2013-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1